Wifi reconnect fails from a ESP32 client to a RaspberryPi set as an Access Point
I was playing around with a ESP32 using Micropython and was trying to connect it over WiFi to a RaspberryPi set as an AP.
The RPi is set as an AP using these commands :
$ sudo nmcli d wifi hotspot ifname wlan0 ssid raspi_ap password raspi_ap_pwd
$ sudo nmcli connection modify Hotspot ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.1/24
$ sudo nmcli connection modify Hotspot connection.autoconnect yes
$ sudo nmcli connection up Hotspot

The code on the ESP is using that function : https://pastebin.com/HQQkfN7F
The connection works well except that if I reset the board by pressing the on-board reset button (which should reset both cores of the ESP), the next connection attempt fails with a STAT_WRONG_PASSWORD code.
I noticed that this next connection after the ESP resets works if I wait for the station to be deassociated on the RaspberryPi side. (I do monitor this using iw dev wlan0 station dump).
I first thought about a problem on the ESP side either on MicroPython or the ESP-IDF level but after trying with another AP (my ISP box), I can't reproduce that issue and the next connection right after a board reset works as expected.
So the issue seems to be on the RPi side.
I tried to monitor using Wireshark what happens during this connection attempt after reset and I can't see any packet sent while I see the EAPOL/DHCP/ARP/MDNS requests that was sent on the previous successful connection.
On the RPi side, I tried to set the log level of NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant to debug and see what happens during this connection attempt after reset and it is the same, nothing is logged on during the connection attempts which fails with STAT_WRONG_PASSWORD code.
However, I can see that during these attempts the inactive time of the station is being reset to 0ms as a result of iw dev wlan0 station dump.
Once the ESP stops to try to connect, I can see the inactive time of the station (from the above iw command) to reach around 60000ms before the station being deassociated removed from there.
After that, if I try to connect the ESP again, it works.
I do post the logs from wpa_supplicant there : https://pastebin.com/nS8NVV7d as it is quite long.
What can explain this behavior ?
Is it an issue with the nl80211 driver ?
Any tips to help me to investigate more for this issue are welcome.
As there seems to be a timeout to deassociate the station from NetworkManager/wpa_supplicant, is there a way to decrease that time ?
There seems to be something sent every 10s from the ESP to the AP to maintain its connection so I guess I could safely reduce that time to ~15s.
